# modifying a script to be more like an actual banner slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to modify this code that I found on stackoverflow to work more like an actual slider.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Lc7cc7u/

1) If on last slider image, I want the next to go back to the first slide.

2) If on the first slider image, I want the back to go back to the last slider image.

3) Is there an easy way to add fade to this to where I can choose between slide and fade?

Thanks!

javascript:

```
$( "#move_left_button" ).click( function() {
        move_left();
} );

$( "#move_right_button" ).click( function() {
        move_right();
} );

function move_left() {
    if( get_acct_left() >= -480 ) {
        $( "#moving_part" ).animate( {
            left: "-=480px"
        }, 1000, function() {
            if( get_acct_left() <= -480 * 2 ) {
                $( "#moving_part" ).attr( "data-direction", "to_right" );
            }
        } );
    }
}
function move_right() {
    if( get_acct_left() < 0 ) {
        $( "#moving_part" ).animate( {
            left: "+=480px"
        }, 1000, function() {
            if( get_acct_left() >= 0 ) {
                $( "#moving_part" ).attr( "data-direction", "to_left" );
            }
        } );
    }
}

function get_acct_left() {
    return parseInt( $( "#moving_part" ).css( "left" ) );
}

function move_to_next() {
    if( $( "#moving_part" ).attr( "data-direction" ) === "to_left" ) {
        move_left();
    } else {
        move_right();
    }
}

setInterval( move_to_next, 4000 );
```

HTML:

```
<div id="images_holder">
    <div id="move_left_button">LEFT</div>
    <div id="move_right_button">RIGTH</div>
    <div id="moving_part" data-direction="to_left">
        <div class="image_holder">
            <span>image 1</span>
            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="image_holder">
            <span>image 2</span>
            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="image_holder">
            <span>image 3</span>
            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#images_holder {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 480px;
    height: 360px;
    color: red;
}
#moving_part {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1440px; /* image_width * number_of_images */
    height: 360px;
    left: 0;
}
.image_holder {
    float: left;
    width: 480px;
    height: 360px;
    position: relative;
}
.image_holder span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 200px;
}

#move_left_button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
#move_right_button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: There is an example of an image slider on this page: https://jqueryui.com/position/#cycler . Maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/qefisi/edit?html,css,js,output)***

Whoever coded that code you shared... **it's a total mi(e)ss.**
Some **constructive reasons**:

- `z-index`ing elements position *can* be avoided by properly formatting HTML placing elements in a more natural order.

```
 <OVERLAY element>    >> BUT WHY?
 <underlay element>   
 -------------------------------
 <underlay element>  
 <OVERLAY element>    >> CORRECT
```

- There's no mean to hardcode the sliding DIV **width** inside the CSS. **Should be dynamic**
- The slide **interval** should be stopped while the gallery is operated by the user. **Clear the interval on gallery hover**
- **Spaghetti** code should be avoided. Count slides. Count widths. **Separate your logic into functions**.
- Images should have an `alt` attribute with the image description. That `alt` attribute is available to the user from every decent CMS editor. So why not use that data instead of hardcoding it? (Just a suggestion)
- **Don't create separate code for the fade effec**t. With a proper HTML and CSS setup it's just about a couple of lines of jQuery to change the gallery effect (see `var efx` in the example below) and the related `animate` code.
- *"good UI = UX up"*. All users are already accustomed to a widely (**properly**) used **gallery animation logic**, and that's if you click on **`NEXT` button > animates the container to the left**. (reverse for `PREV`)

Here you go, simply change the `efx` variable and *see it happen*:

```js
jQuery(function( $ ){

  var efx  = "fade",              // "slide" || "fade"
      animationTime = 600,        // Modify mSeconds as desired
      pauseTime     = 4000,
      $gal = $("#images_holder"), // Cache your elements
      $mov = $("#moving_part"),
      $sli = $mov.find("> div"),
      $btn = $("#prev, #next"),
      $dsc = $("#description"),
      w = $gal.width(),           // Calculate the gallery width!
      n = $sli.length,            // Get the number of slides
      c = 0,                      // Counter // Start index
      itv;                        // Interval

  $mov.width(w*n);                // Dynamically set the width

  // SETUP (fade or slide?)
  if(efx==="fade") $sli.css({position:"absolute", left:0}).fadeOut(0).eq(c).fadeIn(0);

  function populateDescription() {
    $dsc.text( $sli.eq(c).find("img").attr("alt") );
  }

  function anim() {
    c = c<0 ? n-1 : c%n;          // loop-back counter if exceeds
    populateDescription();
    if (efx==="fade") {
      $sli.fadeOut(animationTime).eq(c).stop().fadeIn(animationTime);
    }else if(efx==="slide") {
      $mov.stop().animate({left: -c*w});
    }
  }

  function auto() {
    $btn.stop().fadeOut(); // Hide buttons while autosliding
    $dsc.stop().fadeOut(); // Hide descriptions while autosliding
    itv = setInterval(function(){
      ++c;                 // Increment (just like we do on NEXT click)
      anim();              // and animate!
    }, pauseTime);         // Do every "pause" mSeconds
  }

  function pause() {
    $btn.stop().fadeIn();
    $dsc.stop().fadeIn();
    return clearInterval( itv );      // Clear any ongoing interval!
  }

  $gal.hover(pause, auto);

  $btn.on("click", function(){
    c = this.id==="next" ? ++c : --c; // If next>increment, else decrement
    anim();                           // Animate!
  });


  populateDescription();              // Init the first slide description
  auto();                             // Start the autoslide!

});
```

```css
#images_holder {
  background: red;
  position:   relative;
  overflow:   hidden;
  height:     360px;
  width:      480px;
}
#moving_part {
  position: absolute;
  height:   inherit;
  left:     0;
}
#moving_part > div {
  position: relative;
  height:   inherit;
  width:    480px;
  float:    left;
}
#moving_part > div img{
  width:  100%;
}
#prev, #next {
  position: absolute;
  cursor:   pointer;
  top:      47%; 
  display:  none; /* hide initially */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
#next{
  right: 0px;
}
#description{
  color:      #fff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  text-align: center;
  position:   absolute;
  padding:    15px;
  right:      0;
  left:       0;
  display:    none; /* hide initially */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images_holder">
  <div id="moving_part">
    <div>
      <img alt="Image 1" src="//placehold.it/400x300/c7a&text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img alt="Image description 2" src="//placehold.it/400x300/ac7&text=2">
    </div>
    <div>
      <img alt="Image 3" src="//placehold.it/400x300/7ca&text=3">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="prev">PREV</div>
  <div id="next">NEXT</div>
  <div id="description">Test</div>
</div>
```

*Want to add `navigation buttons` to the code above?* **No problem**:
It's easy to do it cause of the way we used functions. Style your `span` buttons inside CSS, Inside HTML just create a parent element like `<div id="navigation"></div>`.
With jQuery we'll automagically append `span` buttons to it:

```
var $nav = $("#navigation"); // Our buttons parent
var $navBtns;                // Later, our SPAN buttons
var spans = "";
for(var i=0; i<n; i++) {     // `n` is the number of slides!
    spans += "<span>"+ (i+1) +"</span>";
}
// Finally append our generated buttons:
$nav.append( spans );
// Retrieve the created buttons and do something on click
$nav.find("span").on("click", function(){
   c = $(this).index(); // Set our counter to the clicked SPAN index
   anim();              // Animate. That easy.
});
```

***[Demo with navigation buttons](http://jsbin.com/qefisi/2/edit)***

Comment: question was how to modify code  so it is safe to assume  that purpose is learning, so i don't thing complicate replace with something else is not valid option

Comment: @StormRideR I agree with you - that I've modified the code completely (mostly the JS/jQ part) but **for learning purposes**. And giving answers on *"improving"* bed examples is just like learning from bed resources.

Comment: actually I think this is a great thing.  Helping others fix code whether for learning or just to improve code is an awesome use of this system.  Your rendition of the code provided looks amazing.  Great job!  I actually did research and found that on here and stated my question with the code.  The only thing that yours does not do is provide the option to do both slide and fade.  Is there a way to add this to the code?  If not, I understand.  I just think being able to offer different transitions would be a nice feature.  If there are any other transitions that are easy to code in, please do!

Comment: I'd prefer the same code, with different effect options (if possible) inside <img> tag.  I read through your stuff, and this may be in there in your code, just didn't see it in your img tags so no clue how to use it.  The EFX

Comment: Also, two updates I need for your code.  I don't want to use alt text to display text over image.  Alt is used for SEO and I might want different words to display than I want associated with the image in SEO.  Second, I don't want the alt text to only show on mouseover.  I want it to always show.  Can this be changed?

Comment: @KDJ you can than use ALT for seo and `title` attribute to get the description of an image. *How to make the texts immediately visible?* if you follow my comments in the CSS you'll see that `#description` is `display:none`, also you'll see in JS the `populateDescription` function. Modify the code as you need.

Comment: you almost got it to what I want.  I want each image to be able to have its own text; however, don't want to use alt.  I see where you added description.  How can this be modified to allow each image to have its own description?  I absolutely love what you did so far though.  It looks and works amazingly!

Comment: @KDJ ...as I've said, by simply removing from the CSS the `display:none;` stuff (you hopefully know that means `display:none;`) and by removing the stuff from jQuery that fades IN and OUT the buttons etc... You've could easily done that by just exploring the code and following the comments, but here you go: http://jsbin.com/qefisi/4/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @KDJ also, as I've said, instead of using `alt` I added `title` attribute to all our images and used `.attr("title")` insdead of `.attr("alt")` in jQuery inside the `populateDescription` function. All of this changes should not be hard for you to understand and do by your-self in the future, so practice practice practice! Best of luck

Comment: Yeah that looks better; however, something broke.  Its not changing.  sorry, still relatively new to javascript.  I do understand what you are doing now though :)

Comment: @KDJ sorry my mistake, here you go: http://jsbin.com/qefisi/5/edit (I removed the var `$nav` but I've left it later in the code)

Comment: I have attempted to add image 'rel' attribute. Can you tell me what I did wrong?  I attempted to modify yours some to add rel.  This is for learning and attempting to make work with a specific need in mind. http://jsbin.com/sidefomewa/1/edit     ... I added 'wrd' in top, getting attribute 'rel' and also populate code each time you did populate description.  I'm trying to understand how this code works.

Comment: @KDJ you linked an empty jsBin file. Before updating and sending the jsbin link you need to click: Share >> klick to Lock Further changes. Than paste the link for me to see the code.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/sidefomewa/1/edit?html,css,js,output  oops..haha..here you go...this just includes the javascript.

Comment: @KDJ please, consider adding the HTML and JS stuff

Comment: is there a way to modify this code to automatically detect the tallest image and use that as the height of the elements rather than defining the height in the css?

Comment: @KDJ instead of images use background-image set to `background-size: cover` for the slides DIV.

Comment: I've got to use img tags due to how it's got to be used.

Answer (score -1):

here you go: from last it goes back to first  (since point 1 is done there is no case 2)

- number and size of image holder is no longer hardcoded in js

```js
$( "#move_left_button" ).click( function() {
        move_left();
} );

$( "#move_right_button" ).click( function() {
        move_right();
} );
var imgNum=$('.image_holder').length;
var imgWidth=parseInt($('.image_holder').css( "width"));
$( "#moving_part" ).css( "width" ,imgNum*imgWidth +"px" );

function move_left() {
    if( get_acct_left() >= -imgWidth*imgNum) {
        $( "#moving_part" ).animate( {
            left: '-='+imgWidth
        }, 1000, function() {

            if( get_acct_left() <=( -imgWidth * ((imgNum)-1)) ) {
                $( "#moving_part" ).attr( "data-direction", "to_right" );
            }
        } );
    }
}
function move_right() {
    if( get_acct_left() < 0 ) {
        $( "#moving_part" ).animate( {
            left:  '+='+imgWidth
        }, 1000, function() {
            
            if( get_acct_left() >= 0 ) {
                $( "#moving_part" ).attr( "data-direction", "to_left" );
            }
        } );
    }
}

function get_acct_left() {
    return parseInt( $( "#moving_part" ).css( "left" ) );
}

function move_to_next() {
    if( $( "#moving_part" ).attr( "data-direction" ) === "to_left" ) {
        move_left();
    } else {
        move_right();
    }
}

setInterval( move_to_next, 4000 );
```

```css
#images_holder {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 480px;
    height: 360px;
    color: red;
}
#moving_part {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 480px;
    height: 360px;
    left: 0;
}
.image_holder {
    float: left;
    width: 480px;
    height: 360px;
    position: relative;
}
.image_holder span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 200px;
}

#move_left_button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
#move_right_button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div id="images_holder">
    <div id="move_left_button">LEFT</div>
    <div id="move_right_button">RIGTH</div>
    <div id="moving_part" data-direction="to_left">
        <div class="image_holder">
            <span>image 1</span>
            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="image_holder">
            <span>image 2</span>
            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="image_holder">
            <span>image 3</span>
            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
        </div>
          <div class="image_holder">
            <span>image 4</span>
            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Lc7cc7u/8/

enjoy

Fade version

```js
$("#move_left_button").click(function () {
    move_left();
});

$("#move_right_button").click(function () {
    move_right();
});
var imgNum = $('.image_holder').length;
var imgWidth = parseInt($('.image_holder').css("width"));
$("#moving_part").css("width", imgNum * imgWidth + "px");

function move_left() {
    if (get_acct_left() >= -imgWidth * imgNum) {
        $("#moving_part").fadeOut(500, function () {
            $("#moving_part").css("left", (get_acct_left() - imgWidth))
            if (get_acct_left() <= (-imgWidth * ((imgNum) - 1))) {
                $("#moving_part").attr("data-direction", "to_right");
            }

            $("#moving_part").fadeIn(500, function () {});
        });
    }
}

function move_right() {
    if (get_acct_left() < 0) {
        $("#moving_part").fadeOut(500, function () {



            $("#moving_part").css("left", (0))
            $("#moving_part").attr("data-direction", "to_left");
            $("#moving_part").fadeIn(500, function () {});
        });
    }
}

function get_acct_left() {
    return parseInt($("#moving_part").css("left"));
}

function move_to_next() {
    if ($("#moving_part").attr("data-direction") === "to_left") {
        move_left();
    } else {
        move_right();
    }
}

setInterval(move_to_next, 4000);
```

```css
#images_holder {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 480px;
    height: 360px;
    color: red;
}
#moving_part {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 480px;
    height: 360px;
    left: 0;
}
.image_holder {
    float: left;
    width: 480px;
    height: 360px;
    position: relative;
}
.image_holder span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 200px;
}
#move_left_button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
#move_right_button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images_holder">
    <div id="move_left_button">LEFT</div>
    <div id="move_right_button">RIGTH</div>
    <div id="moving_part" data-direction="to_left">
        <div class="image_holder"> <span>image 1</span>

            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="image_holder"> <span>image 2</span>

            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="image_holder"> <span>image 3</span>

            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="image_holder"> <span>image 4</span>

            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h3cnn0xv/

Comment: is there a way to do it where it doesnt go left all the way back to 1; however continues going right and just starts #1 again?  Looks bad to see all the other images/text sliding fast.  Also, any way to add the ability to choose slide/fade?

Comment: @KDJ added separate fade in out version (having both at once is only additional mess in code)

Comment: Why the blinking fade transition? The galleries are broken and unoperable. You cannot click on a user action element and let the code mess the count. If one clicks *LEFT* the gallery should go left, not left and than immediately right.... Messy and not user-friendly

Comment: Also on the *slide* verson... what happens if you bestially (multiple+fast) click on the *left / right* button?! :)